# Should I indicate on Form 1 for 2015 for Massachusetts my current address or my address in 2015?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, massachusetts

I am filling out a [2015 Form 1](https://www.mass.gov/lists/2015-massachusetts-personal-income-tax-forms-and-instructions) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180919085428/https://www.mass.gov/files/documents/2017/12/04/dor-2015-inc-form-1_0.pdf)) for the state of Massachusetts in the United States. My address has changed since 2015: I now live in a different state in the United States. Am I supposed to indicate on Form 1 my current address or my address in 2015?

Note that in April 2016 I did fill another Form 1 for 2015 (but I need to fix it, that's why I fill it again): in April 2016 I had the same address as in 2015.

[image]

The [Form 1 instructions for 2015](https://www.mass.gov/doc/2015-form-1-instructions/download) don't seem to specify it:

> Name and Address: 
>   Print the full name, address, and Social Security
>   number of each person filing the return in the
>   spaces provided. Enter names as they appear on
>   your federal return. Be sure to retain the four-digit
>   Personal Identification Number (PIN) printed on
>   the back cover. You will need it to use DOR’s
>   Web-based and/or Interactive Voice Response
>   (IVR) applications, such as checking the status of
>   your refund.

Answer (score 1):

They want your current address. The purpose of the address is to know where to send correspondence to you (if they have any questions), as well as things like a refund check (if, say, a direct deposit failed for some reason, or your math was wrong and you get a refund you weren't expecting). It's not there to determine residency for tax purposes or anything like that. It's not unusual for people to move, and they want you to tell them your current address, either by putting it on forms you file or specifically by [telling them when you move](https://www.mass.gov/service-details/notify-dor-of-your-change-of-address).

If they had wanted the address as of a specific date, they would have given specific instructions (like "Enter your address as of December 31"). Like the instructions you quoted say, they just want your address, so give them your current address like you'd give anybody else your address.